# XPath selector works in XPath Helper console, but doesn't work in scrapy

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm using scrapy to parse interest rates from [Russian Central Bank website](https://www.cbr.ru/hd_base/zcyc_params/zcyc/?DateTo=01.10.2018)

I'm also using Xpath Helper extension in Google Chrome to find a necessary XPath selector. The selector I use in XPath Helper Console below works exactly as I need.

[image: Xpath Helper Console]

The same query for some reason doesn't work in my spider, even though it navigates to the page.

[image: Spider]

You can see my Spider code below.

```
import scrapy
import urllib.parse

class RatesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
   name = 'rates'
   allowed_domains = ['cbr.ru']
   start_urls = ['https://www.cbr.ru/hd_base/zcyc_params/zcyc/?DateTo=01.10.2018']

   def parse(self, response):

    rates = response.xpath('/html/body/div/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td').extract()

    yield {'Rates': rates
       }
```

The page doesn't seem to be login blocked, because I can parse other elements on the page.

What can I do to make my code work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table doesn't contain that `tbody` node - it's added by browser while rendering page, so just **don't use it in XPath** (`.../table/tbody/tr/...` -> `.../table//tr/...`):

```
rates = response.xpath('/html/body/div/div/div/div/div/table//tr[2]/td').extract()
```

or simplified

```
rates = response.xpath('//td').extract()
```