# Scrapy unable to find data by xpath

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

Page: https://forum.lowyat.net/PropertyForSale

I'm trying to scrape few items from a forum using an older version of IPB (back when it was free).

Using Xpath Helper (Chrome extension), I identified the xpath of the topic title. For example, this:

```
response.xpath("//div[@id='forum_topic_list']/table/tbody/tr[7]/td[@class='row1'][4]/div/div[1]/a[1]").extract()
```

should return:

```
WTS 2 storey terrace house
```

But it doesn't return anything.

Only after widening the scope using the following that I received a response:

```
response.xpath("//div[@id='forum_topic_list']/table").extract()
```

which seems to return the page's html.

I also tried using CSS selectors, which produced better result, using the following:

```
response.css('tr td.row1 div div a::text').extract()
```

Problem is it doesn't return just the topic title.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Just want to clarify the page isn't displaying the data using javascript since I tried disabling javascript it loaded just fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XPath selector works in XPath Helper console, but doen't work in scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52771158/xpath-selector-works-in-xpath-helper-console-but-doent-work-in-scrapy)

Comment: Yep, thank you so much. How did I not see that. I'm sorry!

Comment: @Andersson btw how do you know the tbody tag is added by the browser?

Comment: You can do Right click on page -> Click "View page source" -> check that `<table>` node has no `<tbody>` child node

Comment: Oh I didn't even know the View page source is different from inspect element. Thanks for your help.